# Is there a standard for the trip paperwork packages that are used by the airlines?

Tags: airline-operations, preflight, flight-plans

I have noticed that different airlines (like LIDO, Delta, AA, etc.) have different formats for their trip paperwork packages, containing pre-flight information that they give to their pilots.  These packages contain things like their flight plan, NOTAM's, weather, weight & balance, etc. There is some overlap of course, but I was wondering if FAA/EASA has some standard or guideline for generating the package?

Comment: LIDO is not an airline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For national flights, FAA *prefers* ICAO flight plan. For international flights, ICAO format *must* be used, From [FAA Flight Planning Information](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ato/service_units/air_traffic_services/flight_plan_filing/):

> The FAA prefers users to file ICAO format flight plans for all flights. An ICAO format flight plan MUST be used when:
>
> - The flight will enter international airspace, including oceanic airspace controlled by FAA facilities.
> - The flight expects routing or separation based on Performance Based Navigation (PBN), e.g. RNAV 1.
> - The flight will enter RVSM airspace.
> - The flight expects services based on ADS-B.

EASA follows a format similar to ICAO.

The flight plan usually consists of the following:

- Aircraft type and identification.
- Flight Rules.
- Equipment.
- Source, destination, departure time and (estimated) arrival time.
- Route details.

among other things.

The following image shows the ICAO international flight plan

[image: ICAO flight plan]

Image from *Form 7233-4 - Pre-Flight Pilot Checklist and International Flight Plan* from faa.gov

The following shows the domestic flight plan from FAA. Note that the ICAO format may be followed in domestic flights too.

[image: National flight plan]

Image from *Form 7233-1 - Flight Plan* from faa.gov

Answer (score 1):

The international standard is the ICAO flight plan. For national flights different formats may be allowed.

See [this article on SKYbrary](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Flight_Plan_Filling) for details on what the ICAO flight plan contains.

Answer (score 1):

There are no guidelines by FAA/EASA for preparing flight plans.

As [per FAA,](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ato/service_units/air_traffic_services/flight_plan_filing/) criteria for International (ICAO) Flight Plan Filing are:

> The FAA prefers users to file ICAO format flight plans for all flights. An ICAO format flight plan MUST be used when:
>
> 1. The flight will enter international airspace, including oceanic airspace controlled by FAA facilities.
> 2. The flight expects routing or separation based on Performance Based Navigation (PBN), e.g. RNAV 1.
> 3. The flight will enter RVSM airspace.
> 4. The flight expects services based on ADS-B.

There is a form in Aeronautical Information Manual (AIM) Section 1, Paragraph 5-1-9 that need to be filled with all the required information.

Criteria for Domestic Flight Plan Filing are:

> Flights that remain wholly within domestic United States airspace, and do not meet any of the criteria requiring an ICAO format flight plan, may use an FAA domestic format flight plan.

There is a form in AIM Section 5-1-8 (FAA Form 7233-1) that needs to be filled with all the required information.

File the Flight Plan by any of the following methods.

1. Submit a hard-copy flight plan form to your local flight service
   station.
2. Call Flight Services (1-800-WX-BRIEF or 1-800-992-7433) – The flight services specialist will file your flight plan.
3. Submit your plan online through one of the following free services:
        - Direct User Access Terminal (DUAT)
        - Direct User Access Terminal Service (DUATS)
        - Lockheed Martin Flight Services

Note: All the information is available in www.faa.gov